# Fullcalendar.js custom start date in Weekview?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Basically I would like to show today as the first day of the week in a week view of Fullcalendar js. I have tried to find the right method in the docs without luck. However, abusing `firstDay` with `firstDay: 19` for today (2015-04-24) I could achieve this (week starting today):

[image: fullcalendar weekview first day]

Since this cannot be the correct way, I would like to know a correct solution here. I tried defaultDate and gotoDate, but they did not work.

Comment: please share the js code  for calendar initialization of your attempt. And you should use `firstDay: 0-6`, please check the docs again. Let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Ah, I could solve it now. Indeed I can set `firstDay` to the appropriate weekday. I post the code below.

Answer (score 2):

To set the current day as beginning of week use `firstDay: (new Date().getDay()),`.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek'
    },
    defaultDate: '2015-04-25', // is not setting the Friday to first day in weekview
    editable: false,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    firstDay: (new Date().getDay()), // returns the day number of the week, works! 
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    lang: 'de',
    columnFormat: 'dddd D.M.',
    allDaySlot: false,
    slotDuration: '00:30:00', // default is 30 min
    minTime: '12:00:00',
    maxTime: '23:00:00',
    contentHeight: 600,
    events: [

        {
            title: 'Test',
            start: '2015-04-25T14:00:00',
            end: '2015-04-25T21:00:00',
            dow: [4], // repeat same weekday
            rendering: 'background', 
            color: '#6BA5C2'
        },

    ],

    timezone: 'local',

    // ... 

}); // end fullCalendar
```